# MSVC unresolved external symbol linking executables

Tags: visual-c++, linker, dependencies, dllexport, visual-studio-2010

I have two existing executables A and T, in the same solution that both ran just fine before I touched them.  In executable A is a header defining a class P, and a prototype for a static instance MyP.  The definitions are compiled in project A.  In executable T, I wanted to call member functions of MyP in project A, so I added dllimport/export macros to the declarations of the class and MyP in the headers (not at the definitions), and included the headers in project T.  The dllimport/export macros are standard, and A_EXPORTS is defined in project A, but not in T.

```
#ifdef A_EXPORTS
#define A_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define A_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

//various definitions and includes, defining ENUM_RECORDING_TYPE and ERROR
A_API HFILE viosopen(const _TCHAR *path, ENUM_RECORDING_TYPE rt, int flags);
A_API struct P { 
    ERROR B(SHORT phraseNum);
};
A_API extern P MyP;
```

I added project A as a dependency on project T in the solution.  A still compiles fine, but T comes up with `unresolved external symbol "__declspec(import) <snip> referenced in function <snip>` for the function calls, and `unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class P MyP" <snip>` for the static object.  I also see in the output log, right after it starts linking: `Creating library Debug/A.lib and object Debug/A.exp` which seems ominous since it's supposed to be linking against the existing executable.

My question is: how can I tell MSVC 2010 where those are?  I thought simply setting A as a dependency would have it figure that out automatically.  I can link against the existing executable, right?

Comment: you need to show us your declarations in project A. I'm suspecting that you didn't flag the class and the static instance correctly (using A_API)

Comment: Are you trying to statically link to the implementation of MyP etc. or are you trying to dynamically link to A.exe?

Comment: @Frank Boyne: Since exe and dll are basically the same file format, I figured it could link as if it were a dll, so dynamic.  Static would be better, since I only need four functions, but I don't want to add another project to make a static lib version of A.

Comment: @YeehFei: I copied in the code (with the renamed names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **statically** link your program you don't need the __declspec() stuff and you don't need a separate project to create a LIB file.  I think you can just link using the .obj file from your A project.

Your A project has a header file and presumably has a .cpp file that contains the implementation of the items described in that header.  Let's say your header file is `foo.h` and the associated implementation is `foo.cpp`.  When compiled, there should be a `foo.obj` intermediate file in the `<solutiondir>\A\Debug` or `<solutiondir>\A\release` intermediate folder.  That file can be used by the linker.

In project T's properties, find Linker | Input and change the "Additional Dependencies" property to include the `foo.obj` file.  One approach would be to use a relative file path to locate the file - for example `..\A\Debug\foo.obj` in your debug configuration.  Another approach is to use the simple file name in "Additional Dependencies" - `foo.obj` - and then use Linker | General | Additional Library Directories" to help the linker find the file - e.g., `..\A\$(IntDir)`.  Using the `$(IntDir)` macro has the advantage that the same value works for Debug and Release settings.

Remember to set up a build dependency from your T project to your A project to be sure the A project is compiled first.  Otherwise the `foo.obj` file might not exist when the T linker comes to look for it.  In the Solution properties, select Project Dependencies and then set Project T depends on Project A.

To **dynamically** link you need to use the `A.LIB` file as @ajay said.  The `__declspec(DllImport)` tells the compiler what functions and data you are importing but doesn't tell it where you are importing those things from.

Using the `A.LIB` file as input to the linker is much the same as using the `foo.obj` file in the statically linking case except that the lib file ends up in the solution output directory `<solutiondir>\Debug` instead of the project intermediate directory `<solutiondir>\A\Debug`.

This [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms235636%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on creating and using a DLL might be useful background.

Comment: I never thought to link to the .obj files, that's brilliant!  Lets see if I can make it work

Comment: Just discovered that A is also statically linked with several other projects.  I'll read the DLL walkthrough.

Comment: It's more work but you could think about moving all the common code to a third project that builds a DLL that both project A and project T link to.  You'll be glad you did when project X comes along which also wants to use the common code.

Answer (score 0):

I asssume project A is DLL not an EXE, which is successfully producing a LIB file. 
You need to use the `A.LIB` as Linker Input in project B. Just producing LIB file wont make other projects automatically link to it.

Comment: Nope, project A is a EXE file.