# Access violation on static library call

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker, debug-symbols

As an extension of question [MSVC unresolved external symbol linking executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033637/msvc-unresolved-external-symbol-linking-executables).  `A` contains and a class `P` with two member functions `F` and `G`, and also contains a global `P MyP`. I'm attempting to call functions `MyP.F`, from Executable `T`.  I finally got past the linking part, but now it fails at runtime with the exception.

A.cpp

```
 struct P {
     void F();
     void G();
 } MyP;

 P::F() {
 }
 P::G() {
 }
 int main() {
     MyP.F();
     MyP.G();
 }
```

T.cpp

```
struct P {
     void F();
     void G();
} MyP;

int main() {
    MyP.F();
    MyP.G();
}
```

I can put a breakpoint in `T` at the line where it calls `F` in Visual Studio 2008, but when I press the button to step in, or to step over, I get an exception `First-chance exception at 0xfe5ca589 in A.exe: 0xC0000005: Access reading location 0xfe5ca589`. When I look at the call stack, it shows

> fe5ca589()
>   A.exe!G() + 0x60a6 bytes
>   [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for A.exe]

Both projects are part of the same Visual Studio solution, and `A` is properly set as a dependancy for `T`, and seems to be linking correctly, but I can't step into it.  Does anyone have insights how to make Visual Studio load the symbols for `A` so I can step into it and find the error?  (Or if something is linked funny causing the error?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283482/c-cli-use-loadlibrary-getprocaddress-with-an-exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executables don't have the metadata allowing them to be loaded at an alternate address, and `A.EXE` can't load into `T.EXE` at its desired address, because `T.EXE`'s code is already there.

<strike>You might be able to work around this by changing the default load address of `A.EXE` (when building it, it's a linker option), but the correct solution is to use a DLL.</strike> (Confirmed, [no you can't](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=136276))

Exports from `.EXE` files are provided to allow plugin DLLs to call functions in the main application.  They aren't meant to allow loading the `.EXE` like it was a DLL.

Comment: Aw, that's not good.  I've been working on this for like a month at work, and all I need from `A` is the one class.  So I guess I have to explain to my bosses that what I wanted is not as easily done as I thought, and we have to add an `A_alt` project as a static library for `T` to link against.

Comment: And the windows linker didn't notice that this would be a problem?  Bad Microsoft.

Comment: @Mooing: For more information, search [this explanation of the PE format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) for "relocation".  It might be possible for you to force the linker to emit relocation data in `A.EXE`, or change the load address of `T.EXE` so `A.EXE` doesn't need to be fixed up, but it definitely won't work by default.

Comment: @Mooing: Please note that the call from `T.EXE` to `A.EXE` is always indirect, and can be adjusted to point wherever `A.EXE` actually loaded.  It's the references inside `A.EXE` to data and other functions inside itself that aren't position independent, and that isn't related to the import library that the linker sees while producing `T.EXE`.  I guess the linker could go out and inspect `A.EXE`, but you might use a different version at runtime than the one that existed on the computer where `link` ran.

Comment: @Mooing: Also read [this thread on microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/tree/browse_frm/thread/92191044b279b0bd/d6f6cd92538820af?rnum=1&q=win32+kernel+loadlibrary+exe+relocations&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fmicrosoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2F92191044b279b0bd%2Ff3f4cd0a421bb0c4%3Fq%3Dwin32%2Bkernel%2Bloadlibrary%2Bexe%2Brelocations%26#doc_5278316213891a6b)

Comment: `This field seems relevant only for OBJ files.`  That's awe-inspiring right there.  "We think this is how our stuff works, but we're not sure."

Comment: @Mooing: The author is likely an invited guest, not the MS engineer who wrote the loader.

Comment: LoadLibrary is for dynamic linking.  Static is preferred, but I guess I can try dynamic linking, and see how far I get.

Comment: @Mooing: `LoadLibrary` vs import table doesn't matter, both call the same loader code.